# How do i find and reconize the chrome browser control command-line

Tags: google-chrome, browser, command-line, console

I am in the chrome browser console and need instructions to find the command line.

I have tried to google the question and also tried to find the answer on youtube.

No code to show

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question and what you are trying to achieve

[To open the dedicated Console panel:](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Windows / Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Mac).

---

One way to open commmand line (**Command Prompt**) in Windows
1. Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
2. type in *cmd.exe* and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>